# Сапер. Проверка нулевых клеток

Tags: java

Java
Если нажимаем на пустую клетку, все пустые вокруг открываются до непустых.
Кажется происходит зацикливание, пока не могу понять почему

```
//Внутри проверки клетки по нажатию, условие - клетка пустая (ее значение 0)
//arrayOfActions - очередь ArrayDeque из координат
arrayOfActions.addLast(i);
arrayOfActions.addLast(j);
while (arrayOfActions.size() != 0){

      checkFields(arrayOfActions.poll(),arrayOfActions.poll());//Проверка клеток смежных
}
```

......
    //Закончилась функция проверки нажатия кнопок

```
boolean checkFields(int i, int j)
    {
        states[i][j] = State.OPENED; //Состояние: открытая клетка
        if(j != 0) {
            if (field[i][j - 1] == CellValue.NUMBER) {   //Число, не бомба
                if (fieldValues[i][j - 1] != 0) {  //Если не пустая(нулевая)
                    states[i][j - 1] = State.OPENED;
                } else { 
                    arrayOfActions.addLast(i);
                    arrayOfActions.addLast(j - 1);
                }
            }
        }
        if(j != n-1) {
            if (field[i][j + 1] == CellValue.NUMBER) {
                if (fieldValues[i][j + 1] != 0) {
                    states[i][j + 1] = State.OPENED;
                } else {
                    arrayOfActions.addLast(i);
                    arrayOfActions.addLast(j + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        if(i != 0) {
            if (field[i - 1][j] == CellValue.NUMBER) {
                if (fieldValues[i - 1][j] != 0) {
                    states[i - 1][j] = State.OPENED;
                } else {
                    arrayOfActions.addLast(i - 1);
                    arrayOfActions.addLast(j);
                }
            }
        }
        if(i != n-1) {
            if (field[i + 1][j] == CellValue.NUMBER) {
                if (fieldValues[i + 1][j] != 0) {
                    states[i + 1][j] = State.OPENED;
                } else {
                    arrayOfActions.addLast(i + 1);
                    arrayOfActions.addLast(j);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: оффтоп: переменная field не полностью описывает себя. Она должна содержать и состояние, и  значение. Думаю, если вы не захотите это дело объединить под единым классом, эта переменная должна называться fieldValues(-s, так как это массив), а states - fieldStates

Comment: Ну не в этом же проблема

Comment: field просто массив со значениями enum(NUMBER, UNDEFINED, BOMB)

Comment: А таковым быть не должен,  так как он не полностью описывает понятие "поле". Объект поля, в нашем случае, полностью характеризуется значением и состоянием. У вас же оно характеризуется только состоянием. И еще - я прямо указал, что это замечание не относится к вопросу напрямую, написав слово "оффтоп" .

Comment: Всем спасибо за участие, уже все сам исправил.